# How to remove terrain in 3d?

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, terrain

After the release of Minecraft I saw more and more rip offs of the game but some actually began to change it up a bit making the game have a organic look instead of the iconic blocky one that Minecraft does. 
If you'd like to look at the game that i'm referring to you can do so [here](http://store.steampowered.com/app/324080/). If you skip to around 50 seconds on the first video the steam page offers you can see the mining part that i'm wondering about. 

I was wondering how this affect is achieved where they are able to remove part of the 3D object on collison with the players pick. I have heard about constructive solid geometry before and figured that could have been used but i'm not so sure.

Answer (score 0):

It could be Constructive Solid Geometry indeed. But they said in the store page it is a [voxel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel)-based world (unless they lied of course). Which is basically pixels in 3D (or i could say cubes in the case of minecraft, and others).

In this case, it seems to me they smooth out those voxels to achieve that organic looks. Something like [Castle Story](http://www.castlestory.net/) which you can clearly see some are smoothen out, well not everything is like in Rising World, but you get my point.